# I can't find a pattern of this 6*6 matrix

Tags: algorithm

It's a kind of programming practice problem.

## The question is, "Print this matrix".

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5  0
0  1  2  3  0  1
5  0  5  4  1  2
4  5  4  3  2  3
3  2  1  0  5  4
```

=========================

Well, I can use 'printf' for 16 times, but I don't wanna do that.
There would be some pattern.. 
But really, I couldn't figure it out. I struggled with it for a week..!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a clockwise spiral starting at the top left.